# GARCH option pricing

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-processes, risk-neutral-measure, garch, stochastic-volatility

I have been trying to implement GARCH(1,1) model for pricing call options. Suppose I have calibrated Garch(1,1) model for modelling the conditional volatility using the historical data of an equity through MLE. Now I want to price some call options for that particular equity for that I had tried to use the following risk neutral SDE:
$$dS_t = rS_t + \sigma(t)S_tdB_t$$
It can be checked that the discounted stock price process $e^{(-rt)}S_t$ is a martingale(Source - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266010/conditional-expectation-of-exponential-brownian-motion?noredirect=1&lq=1). So as long as the discounted stock price process is a martingale the price of options is simply the given by the expectation of the discounted payoffs(Monte Carlo approach for pricing). $\sigma(t)$ is the forecasted Garch volatility that I have used for simulating the price process but this approach is overpricing the call options very much. I am aware of the work done by Duan 1995 but I am curious to know what may have gone wrong in this approach.

Further instead of $\sigma(t)$ I also used the long term variance or the unconditional variance then in that case the option prices that I am getting is good enough but for this we are assuming that the volatility is constant which I don't want.

Comment: Your SDE is Black-Scholes. As far as I know the GARCH model is used to estimate presumably your vol from a historical time series. I am not surprised that this doesn't lead to correct option prices because the latter are quoted by option traders (supply and demand). If we are not close to an option maturity there is nothing that links BS vol directly to a historical vol. Have you made sure you estimate the vol of $dS/S$, not $dS$ ?

Comment: Yes I had made sure that the estimated volatility was of $dS/S$.  I will give you an update on this later.